# How do I use projection to insert data in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to write to the database using projection to avoid having to map a domain object to one that matches the table layout. Every projection example that I find however only shows how to read from the database. How do I project my entity to its database version to insert it?

```cs
class Foo
{
   //...
}

class FooEF
{
   //...
}

DbSet<FooEF> dbSet;

// Read
var foos = dbSet.Select(fooEF => new Foo { ... }).ToList();

// Write
???
```

Comment: You create the objects, set the attributes and call `SaveChanges`. As for `Every example that I find however only shows how to read from the database.` on the contrary, all tutorials show how to add objects, otherwise they wouldn't be able to run.

Comment: Are you trying to use EF Core as a replacement for SQL and the `INSERT SELECT` statement perhaps? EF Core is an ORM, not a data access library (that's ADO.NET) or a replacement for SQL. It's used to load objects, modify them and persist them. If you want to use `INSERT ... SELECT` you'll have to use ADO.NET and, perhaps, a microORM like Dapper just to get rid of the boilerplate.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am trying to use projection, and thus trying to avoid creating an intermediate object and wasting performance.

Comment: By projection you mean `INSERT SELECT`? Don't use an ORM then. Write the statement. EF Core is an ORM, not a query builder. There are some query builder libraries you can use to construct your query

Comment: Projection is only used when querying a database, not when inserting into a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with EF Core. Any Insert/Update/Delete should go via change tracker.

Anyway there is extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) which can help in such query (disclaimer: I'm one of the creators)

```
var foos = dbSet.Select(fooEF => new Foo { ... });

foos.Insert(dbSetFoo.ToLinqToDBTable(), x => x);
```

Extension will create `INSERT FROM` SQL and no data will be transferred to the client.

Comment: I understand now that the change tracker would no longer work if I used projections. I'll try to use mapping with the `ModelBuilder` instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your db context. And you have to define dbSet for `Foo` type

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> DbSetFoo{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<FooEF> DbSetFooEF { get; set; }
    ...
}

...

var foos = dbSet.Select(fooEF => new Foo {...})
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(foo=>context.DbSetFoo.Add(foo));
context.SaveChanges();
```